# Can I move the static access to the base class?

Tags: c#

I have a base and derived class like so:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
   protected string _data;
   protected string GetData_Internal() {return _data;}
   protected abstract void SetData(string data);
}

public class MyDerived : MyBase
{
   protected override void SetData(string data) {_data = "my data";}

   public static string GetData()
   {
      var instance = new MyDerived();
      return instance.GetData_Internal();
   }
}
```

The desired usage of this class is like this:

```
string data1 = MyDerived.GetData();
string data2 = MyDerived2.GetData(); // another class dervied from MyBase
```

I can't make the classes static, because static classes and derived classes don't play well together. So I made the function `GetData()` static, and this allows me to use the class like I want to.

I am going to have multiple classes that all identical to `MyDerived`, except for the data values set in `SetData()`.

I would like to move `GetData()` out of the derived class and into the base class so that I'm not duplicating that code in every single derived class.

I can't figure out how to do that, because a static method in the base class has no idea what type of object to new up.

So, is there any way to do what I'm trying to do, keeping a static interaction with the class, while avoiding code duplication to make it happen?

Comment: Choose static or inheritance; you can't have both.

Comment: Where is the `static interface`?  And from what I can tell from your example you don't want / need to use any static methods at all.  Stick to instances.

Comment: @PhilipPittle Read the "desired usage" bit - OP wants to call the inherited members statically.

Comment: Why do you want this to be a static method? you are creating an instance of the class anyway, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, the OP has stated the desire to call the members statically, but hasn't justified the reasoning for doing so.

Comment: How are you arriving at `MyDerived2`?

Comment: A design goal would be nice to know because given the example as provided there are much more straightforward ways to accomplish the requirement.

Comment: Side note: "interface" have very specific meaning in C# and it does not seem to match how you use "interface" in you post. Please consider re-wording to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Pilip, I want to interact with the class through a static method because I think that leaves the code a lot cleaner and easier to read.  However, the responses that I'm getting here seem to indicate that this is not the way things are done in C#.

Comment: @me how, MyDerived2 is exactly like MyDerived, but with different data set in `MyData()` and, obviously, a different class name.

Comment: New'ing up object in `GetData` looks very strange especially since you have instance method to `SetData`... Maybe suggested singleton answer is actually what you are looking for (also I generally dislike singletons, so can't vote that answer up :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with static data, maybe what you need are singleton objects that can be instantiated only once. They have the advantage of supporting inheritance and interface implementation, as well as being accessible statically. Also, unlike static classes, they can be passed as arguments to methods and stored in fields, properties and variables.

You can use properties instead of getter and setter methods. This simplifies your base class:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

You can implement the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) like this:

```
public class MyDerived : MyBase
{
    #region Singleton Pattern

    public static readonly MyDerived Instance = new MyDerived();

    private MyDerived()
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Create a public static readonly field that returns the only instance of the class and make the constructor private in order to forbid creating instances outside of the class itself. The constructor can also initialize the value of `Data` if required.

You can use the singletons like this:

```
MyDerived.Instance.Data = "my data";
string data = MyDerived.Instance.Data;

MyDerived2.Instance.Data = "my data 2";
...
```

See also: [Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for various ways of implementing the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not completely sure what it is you are trying to accomplish. So, I am making no comment on if any of this is a good idea. You can get behavior that acts somewhat like overridden methods on base classes with statics. Instead, you overwrite the base then call into it. I do something similar to this for fetching instances or collections of instances from the class:

```
public class Dog
{
    public static Dog GetById(int dogId) 
    { 
        //Return dog 
    }
}

public class Lab : Dog
{
    public new static Lab GetById(int dogId) 
    { 
        //Return same dog, as a lab 
    }
}
```

A quick and terrible, but hopefully useful, version might start like the following. I might be able to make it into something practical if I understand your intentions a bit better.

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    public static string GetData()
    {
        return "BASE STUFF";
    }
}

public class MyDerivedA : MyBase
{
    protected const string MySpecialData = "AAAAAA";

    public new static string GetData()
    {
        return MyBase.GetData() + MySpecialData;
    }
}

public class MyDerivedB : MyBase
{
    protected const string MySpecialData = "BBBBBBB";

    public new static string GetData()
    {
        return MyBase.GetData() + MySpecialData;
    }
}
```